# Where does the root of this tree come from?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recursion, recursive-algorithms, trees

I am doing a practice question from  [Midterm Dynamic Programming](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s10/www/midterm/mterm.pdf)

**The Problem** :
Consider a row of n numbers a1, ..., an. The numbers are all positive, and n is even. We play a
game against an opponent, alternating turns. In each turn, a player selects either the first or last
number, removes it from the row, and collects that much money.

For example, if the numbers are 1,2,3,4 , a possible game may look like:

1. Player A takes 4: row is 1,2,3.
2. Player B takes 3: row is 1,2.
3. Player A takes 1: row is 2.
4. Player B takes 2, game over.

Both players ended with a total amount of 5. Note that A could have done better.

(2 pts) Show an example where the greedy algorithm fails to achieve the highest possible amount of money.

Here is the solution to the problem  [Greedy Sol](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s10/www/midterm/mtermsol.pdf) 
[image]

In the diagram, does anyone know where the 11, the root of the tree, is coming from? I thought it was the highest possible amount of money but that be 13 here (10 + 3).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this diagram represents both players playing **optimally**. Every value inside the node(rectangle/circle) is the highest possible value the first play can obtain if both players play optimally. After the first step of the first player, there are two possible states {2,10,3} and {1,2,10}. In {1,2,10} it is the second player's turn and if she/he plays optimally, the highest value the first player can obtain is 2 (the second player will remove 10 first to be optimal). However, if the first player remove 1 first (thus the state {2,10,3}), then no matter how the second player remove next, the first player will remove 10 in her/his second turn to be optimal. Thus highest value the first player can obtain is $$\max\{3 + 2, 1 + 10\}=11$$

Comment: +1: Excellent observation! I think, though, that the values in the rectangles indicate the highest value the second player can obtain from that point (again, assuming that both are playing optimally).

Comment: @CameronBuie No. When it is a rectangle, it is the second player's turn to remove a value. For example, since leaves are all second player's turns, their values are 0 for the first player.

Comment: /shakes head/ Right you are! Looks like it's my bedtime. :-\